# Can I use clustering to detect changes between datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I'm performing analysis for a colleague who has data from two biological conditions. Since clustering is a standard in our field, she'd like to perform clustering on each condition separately, with the goal of identifying datapoints that change clusters between conditions. For example:

[image]

Here, we'd want to flag datapoint 3 as changing clusters. This seems straightforward (look how simple the example is!).

However, there's extra complexity because I'm required to choose the number of clusters a priori, and this changes the result. For example if there's one cluster, datapoint 3 would not be flagged in the example above; if there are three clusters, other datapoints would also be flagged. So, **is clustering a viable/appropriate method for doing what we want**? If so, **is there a conventional method that doesn't require choosing the number of clusters beforehand**?

Comment: To detect changes you don't need clustering at all. Why the idea of clusters haunts you?

Comment: I, like @ttnphns think clustering doesn't look like it buys you anything here. Could probably make it work, but there are probably better methods. Is there jitter in the data, i.e. do each of the points move a little from case A to case B?

Comment: @ttnphns I'm curious if clustering could be used here, and, if it could, a good way to use it. I don't mean to argue it's the best method.

Comment: @MattL. Yes, there is jitter between A and B (experimental noise and effects from the conditions).

Comment: When moving from condition A to condition B, one source of variability is change of 'underlying cluster'. You also mention jitter/experimental noise. Is this something like additive noise on top of a true/underlying position, or like drawing an independent sample from the same underlying cluster, or something else? It seems like the fundamental problem is how to distinguish between these sources of variability, so knowing more about them would help. Can you tell us anything more about the data or its properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought up one possible solution utilizing clustering.

1. Cluster case A
2. For case B use same cluster assignments.
3. Calculate the distance to the cluster center for each point in A.
4. Calculate distance from cluster points to cluster centers in B.
5. Compare A to B and set some threshold where if a distance exceeds X a flag is set. This would be your data point(s) of interest.

This doesn't really tell you if a cluster switched, but it does tell you if a point(s) have exceed some threshold from their assigned cluster. Might be interesting to include inter-cluster distances too.

Comment: To look for points that change custers, you can use the clustering A as starting point for k-means applied to B. This will change points that have moved closer to a different cluster compared to their original cluster. Beware however that the result depends on the measurement units, but as you consider clustering, you prabably already apply some varaible normalization scheme.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform clustering without setting number of clusters, then non-parametric methods are something you may try. In particular, you can consider using dirichlet process.

Google give me the following material, https://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~jcorso/t/2009S_555/files/lecture7.dirichlet.pdf.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking about determining the number of clusters.  It is a interesting link though.

Comment: @altria Thank you. Yes, Michael Chernick is correct. I'm more asking whether clustering is the right tool for this analysis.